# How to prevent CSRF Attack in ajax application

Tags: ajax, csrf

can anyone help me how to prevent csrf attack in ajax application. in our application ( PHP + JQuery ) main form is loaded only once and all other forms will be loaded on request using ajax . For Example, when the user click customer , the page will be loaded using ajax request. how do i prevent so that customer page should not be called directly or how do generate and use CSRF token to prevent this

Answer (score 0):

You must try this in your .htaccess file .

```
 # Don't allow any pages to be framed - Defends against CSRF
 Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
```

[read Full Article here](http://stopmalvertising.com/security/securing-your-website-with-.htaccess/.htaccess-http-headers.html)